# Winform - Using Dictionary as Datasource for Combo Box - How to shows keys as selected value in combo box but display Value in drop down box?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, combobox

I am a question regarding to using Dictionary as Datasource for Combo box

Please see the code below:

```
        public readonly Dictionary<string, string> Provinces = new()
        {
            { "01", "Ontario" },
            { "02", "Quebec" },
            { "03", "British Columbia" }
        };


        public ProvincesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.cbProvinces.DataSource = new BindingSource(Provinces, null) ;
            this.cbProvinces.DisplayMember = "Value";
            this.cbProvinces.ValueMember = "Key";

        }
```

When the user click on the combo box, it see a list of values which is my preferences.  Once the user selected the value from the drop down list, I like the combo box to display the key in the combo box instead of the value. ex:  if the user select "Ontario", I like the combo box to show "01" instead of "Ontario"

Thank you,

I have tried switching the DisplayMember and ValueMember but the result still not what I like.

Comment: In `SelectedIndexChanged`, you can `BeginInvoke()` to set the Text property to another value

Comment: BTW, always set the `DisplayMemeber` and `ValueMember` before the `DataSource`. You do the opposite only when you're dealing with a CheckedListBox (you find out why when you try to set its DataSource)